# Tekkit Lite 0.6.5: What is up with liquids?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have been playing on my Tekkit Lite server lately and have been trying to set up a system that transfers lava via cells. I just found that lava buckets will not place the lava. It will consume the lava bucket rendering an empty bucket. Oddly enough, when you right click the bucket again it will be full. This behavior also happens with water and cells, and cells cannot even pick up fluids. The lava cell will appear in your inventory, but not consume the lava/water block, and as soon as you right click or open your inventory it will become an empty cell. However none of this occurs in singleplayer.

What is happening?

Comment: In vanilla, this issue is usually caused by the client thinking the bucket was used successfully, but the server thinking that it was not, causing desync. A mod may be causing the server to think you cannot use buckets or something like that.

Comment: I found that this only happens sometimes and is fixed if the server is restarted.

Comment: Adding to Silentvenom7's comment, to fix this - It's usually the case of "GET [a] BETTER INTERNET [connection]" (Yes, some people do bark this down other peoples' throats), and it means either for yourself, the server or both.

Answer (score 1):

The best choice for you is to go to the mod designers for this. We try to keep the questions here vanilla, as many people don't quite understand the mods the same way we do vanilla games. In any case, it is likely a client-sided issue involving internet connection.

Comment: Very much agreed.